# Proof of Green's identity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, laplacian

Can anyone explain to me how to prove Green's identity by integrating the divergence theorem?

I don't understand how divergence, total derivative, and Laplace are related to each other.

Why is this true:

> $$\nabla \cdot (u\nabla v) = u\Delta v + \nabla u \cdot \nabla v?$$

How do we integrate both parts?
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

The identity follows from the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot g(x))=\frac{df}{dx}(x)g(x)+f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}(x).
$$
for two functions $f$ and $g$. Noting that $\nabla\cdot\nabla=\Delta$ we get
$$
\nabla u\cdot \nabla v+u\nabla\cdot\nabla v =\nabla u\cdot \nabla v+ u\Delta v.
$$
Applying the divergence theorem
$$
\int_{V}(\nabla\cdot \underline{F})dV=\int_{S}\underline{F}\cdot \underline{n}dS
$$
(where $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n,~S$ is its boundary, $\underline{F}$ is a vector field and $\underline{n}$ is the outward unit normal from the surface) and inserting it into the above identity gives 
$$
\int_S u(\nabla v).\underline{n}dS=\int_V u\Delta v+(\nabla u)\cdot (\nabla v) dV,
$$
ie, Green's first identity.